# Taking input from an echoed text field in PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html, forms, field, echo

How do you get input from the text field in the following code?

```
<?php

echo "<form action='signup.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Username' name='username'/>";
echo "<button type='submit' name = 'submit' value='Register' >Sign up</button>";
echo "</form>";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,"vaccinations");
$Iusername = $_POST['username'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$Iusername = $_POST['username'];
echo $Iusername;
echo "whadddup";
}

?>
```

This is giving me username is an undefined index. I need to grab the inputted data in the text field that was echoed

Comment: Right after `$conn`, you have `$Iusername = $_POST['username'];`. And for every time you access this code and don't submit the form (when you first access it), it will generate that warning. Simple fix: Remove that line, because you define it within the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` (no need to define it twice)

Comment: `$Iusername = $_POST['username'];` remove it, because you have it in `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` condition and that is enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the first `$Iusername = $_POST['username'];` and it will work fine.

Explanation:-

Each time when your page is loaded the above line is going to execute. And since `$_POST['username']` have no value at that time (because it will have value if and only if form submits), your above statement fails and give you the warning of `Undefined Index`.